# Create folder and upload images in php/codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a simple image upload form on my website where users can upload multiple images at once. I want to have my images organized in folder based on the month and year in the following format: MONTH-YEAR, so each time new upload starts I first check whether that folder exists or not, and create one if it doesn't exists.

The problem is that if the folder doesn't exists for the current month and I try to upload an image, the folder, representing this current month, is created properly, but then no image is uploaded. But if the folder already exists all the images can be uploaded without any problem. Here is my code:

```
    $folderName = date('m-y');
    $pathToUpload = './uploads/photos/' . $folderName;
    if ( ! file_exists($pathToUpload) )
    {
        $create = mkdir($pathToUpload, 0777);
        $createThumbsFolder = mkdir($pathToUpload . '/thumbs', 0777);
        if ( ! $create || ! $createThumbsFolder)
        return;
    }

    $imgName= uniqid('', TRUE);
    $config['upload_path'] = $pathToUpload;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '9999';
    $config['file_name'] = $imgName . '.jpg';

    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $upload = $this->upload->do_upload("Filedata");
```

Any ideas why the upload doesn't work for the very first time?

Comment: Try this: `if !( $create && $createThumbsFolder)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't listen to these guys.  You're logic is fine--if `mkdir()` returns false either time, then it should fail.

However, as mazzzzz suggests, I would throw an exception in that case, rather than returning false.

I would also do this (rather than multiple calls to `mkdir()`):

```
<?php
mkdir($pathToUpload . '/thumbs', 0777, TRUE);
```

This will recursive create all missing directories needed to create the thumbs folder, which I suspect is where you're failing anyway.

If that's not the case, then somehow you don't have privileges, which seems unlikely if you can upload files.

Additionally, you might have a stat cache problem.  Try running `clearstatcache()` before `do_upload()`

Answer (score 0):

To further The Jumping Frog's answer in the comments, it looks like you could be returning before uploading because you aren't throwing an error, but just silently failing if it is believed the folders aren't being created, even though they are.

If you realize that `$create` and `$createThumbsFolder` should both be true for the program to continue, then you can test the `if` statement's logic.  The if says basically `if (!true || !true)`, meaning `if (false || false)`, which can be simplified to `if (true)` because if either are false it returns true.  Where as Frog's solution says `if (!(true && true))` simplified to `if (!true)` simplified to `if (false)`, so there if both values are what are wanted (and expected) it won't return.

Hope that helps explain the logic error a bit, good luck on the uploader!

P.S. Don't silent fail!